# How to do an onListItemClick?

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` and I want to do a `setOnListItemClick` on my `Listview` but I seem unable to do it.

I am only able to do it with ListActivity but I need an `EditText` so I can't use the `ListActivity`.

Can anyone help me?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);

    arrayA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, eventTitle);
    setListAdapter(arrayA);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked

}
```

Comment: Just because you use `ListActivity` doesn't mean you can't have other `View`s, such as `EditText` in the layout.  You just have to also have a `ListView`.

Comment: Show me the code you have tried. What do you mean "unable to do it"? Does it throw an error? Are you unsure of the syntax? And what are you talking about an EditText - I thought you were trying to setOnListItemClick? What does an EditText have to do with this? :)

Comment: it will throw an error, when i put setContent. i need the edit text for me to perform a search. codes with be up now.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a listactivity youcan use other layout elements and views. The only rule is, there must be a listview with an id as @android:id/list. Here's the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) explaining it clearly. So there should be nothing preventing you from using an edittext in an listactivity. Are you having doubt's on creating a xml layout with an edittext and listview?